# Max value in Array (StdClass error)

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops

**$gameAPI->games**

```
"games": [
        {
            "appid": 10,
            "playtime_forever": 32
        },
        {
            "appid": 20,
            "playtime_forever": 0
        },
        {
            "appid": 30,
            "playtime_forever": 0
        },
        ]
```

I want to get the appid + playtime_forever data where playtime_forever has the highest value in the list.

I used the following code:

```
$data = array_reduce($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return @$a['playtime_forever'] > $b['playtime_forever'] ? $a : $b;
});
```

Where $data = $gameAPI->games;

However I got the following error: *Cannot use object of type stdClass as array*. On line:

```
return @$a['playtime_forever'] > $b['playtime_forever'] ? $a : $b;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your errors states, you are using Object as Array. To access Object properties in PHP, use arrow notation `->`:

```
return $a->playtime_forever > $b->playtime_forever ? $a : $b;
```